# Json normalize Facebook graph API

Tags: json, pandas, dataframe, facebook-graph-api, json-normalize

I'm trying to normalize json request from Facebook Graph into a dataframe but only get 1 row with 4 columns as per table bellow.

I pull the request using request method

```
import requests
from pandas import json_normalize
url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/act_1135563643203528/campaigns?fields=name,date_preset=last_7d,insights{actions,action_values,conversions,conversion_values,impressions}&access_token='+my_access_token

response = requests.get(url)
dictr = response.json()
df = json_normalize(dictr)
```

| data | paging.cursors.before | paging.cursors.after | paging.next |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [{'name': 'SALES CAMPAIG | QVVVV | QQQQQ | https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/act_.... |

I'd like to have a df as bellow table with all actions for analytics (results from request bellow)

| name | post_reaction | ..... | omni_purchase |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CAMPAIGN 1 | 200 | ... | 500 |
| CAMPAIGN 2 | 111 | ... | 222 |

Json response

```
{'data': [{'name': 'SALES CAMPAIGN 1',
   'insights': {'data': [{'actions': [{'action_type': 'comment',
        'value': '11'},
       {'action_type': 'link_click', 'value': '440'},
       {'action_type': 'post_reaction', 'value': '48'},
       {'action_type': 'onsite_conversion.post_save', 'value': '2'},
       {'action_type': 'offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_purchase', 'value': '10'},
       {'action_type': 'offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_view_content',
        'value': '16'},
       {'action_type': 'offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_initiate_checkout',
        'value': '8'},
       {'action_type': 'landing_page_view', 'value': '282'},
       {'action_type': 'offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_search', 'value': '74'},
       {'action_type': 'post_engagement', 'value': '501'},
       {'action_type': 'page_engagement', 'value': '501'},
       {'action_type': 'omni_purchase', 'value': '10'},
       {'action_type': 'omni_view_content', 'value': '16'},
       {'action_type': 'omni_initiated_checkout', 'value': '8'},
       {'action_type': 'omni_search', 'value': '74'},
       {'action_type': 'purchase', 'value': '10'},
       {'action_type': 'view_content', 'value': '16'},
       {'action_type': 'initiate_checkout', 'value': '8'},
       {'action_type': 'search', 'value': '74'}],
      'action_values': [{'action_type': 'offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_purchase',
        'value': '18532'},
       {'action_type': 'offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_view_content',
        'value': '12135'},
       {'action_type': 'offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_initiate_checkout',
        'value': '6530'},
       {'action_type': 'omni_purchase', 'value': '18532'},
       {'action_type': 'omni_view_content', 'value': '12135'},
       {'action_type': 'omni_initiated_checkout', 'value': '6530'},
       {'action_type': 'initiate_checkout', 'value': '6530'}],
      'impressions': '85349',
      'date_start': '2022-05-22',
      'date_stop': '2022-06-20'}],
    'paging': {'cursors': {'before': 'MAZDZD', 'after': 'MAZDZD'}}},
   'id': '2372040507'},
...
  {'name': 'SALES CAMPAIGN 5',
   'insights': {'data': [{'actions': [{'action_type': 'onsite_conversion.post_save',
        'value': '2'},
       {'action_type': 'post', 'value': '3'},
       {'action_type': 'comment', 'value': '21'},
       {'action_type': 'link_click', 'value': '1387'},
       {'action_type': 'post_reaction', 'value': '64'},
       {'action_type': 'landing_page_view', 'value': '934'},
       {'action_type': 'offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_purchase', 'value': '20'},
       {'action_type': 'offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_view_content',
        'value': '42'},
       {'action_type': 'offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_initiate_checkout',
        'value': '15'},
       {'action_type': 'offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_search', 'value': '192'},
       {'action_type': 'post_engagement', 'value': '1477'},
       {'action_type': 'page_engagement', 'value': '1477'},
       {'action_type': 'omni_purchase', 'value': '20'},
       {'action_type': 'omni_view_content', 'value': '42'},
       {'action_type': 'omni_initiated_checkout', 'value': '15'},
       {'action_type': 'omni_search', 'value': '192'},
       {'action_type': 'purchase', 'value': '20'},
       {'action_type': 'view_content', 'value': '42'},
       {'action_type': 'initiate_checkout', 'value': '15'},
       {'action_type': 'search', 'value': '192'}],
      'action_values': [{'action_type': 'offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_purchase',
        'value': '48140'},
       {'action_type': 'offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_view_content',
        'value': '36319'},
       {'action_type': 'offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_initiate_checkout',
        'value': '11716'},
       {'action_type': 'omni_purchase', 'value': '48140'},
       {'action_type': 'omni_view_content', 'value': '36319'},
       {'action_type': 'omni_initiated_checkout', 'value': '11716'},
       {'action_type': 'initiate_checkout', 'value': '11716'}],
      'impressions': '280587',
      'date_start': '2022-05-22',
      'date_stop': '2022-06-20'}],
    'paging': {'cursors': {'before': 'MAZDZD', 'after': 'MAZDZD'}}},
  ],
 'paging': {'cursors': {'before': 'QVVVV',
   'after': 'QQQQ'},
  'next': 'https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/act_111111111/campaigns?access_token=TOKEN#'}}
```

Comment: just to add normalizing with max_level 1,2,3 etc  doesn't do anything to the df

Answer (score 0):

after working with json and pandas a bit more I found a solution.

The workaround is as follows:

```
insights_dive = dictr['data'] ##expanding json on dic named data
df1 = json_normalize(insights_dive) #then you normalize
df1 = df1.explode('name_of_column_containg_nested_Json') ###called actions or action.values
df1 = pd.json_normalize(json.loads(df1.to_json(orient = 'records'))) ##load df as json and unpack the json request into a column
df_pivot = df1.pivot_table('actions.value', ['name', 'id','insights.data.impressions'], 'actions.action_type') ##you use piviot function to convert a column into rows
df_pivot=df_pivot.reset_index() ##reset index to remove rows with names
''''
for action values the procedure is similar, you can create a seperate df and go trough the above and concat two dfs into 1 on name or id etc.
```